# Use of Literals, yay/nay in C++

Tags: c++, sizeof, literals

I've recently heard that in some cases, programmers believe that you should never use literals in your code.  I understand that in some cases, assigning a variable name to a given number can be helpful (especially in terms of maintenance if that number is used elsewhere).  However, consider the following case studies:

Case Study 1:  Use of Literals for "special" byte codes.

Say you have an if statement that checks for a specific value stored in (for the sake of argument) a `uint16_t`.  Here are the two code samples:

Version 1:

```
// Descriptive comment as to why I'm using 0xBEEF goes here
if (my_var == 0xBEEF) {
  //do something
}
```

Version 2:

```
const uint16_t kSuperDescriptiveVarName = 0xBEEF;
if (my_var  == kSuperDescriptiveVarName) {
  // do something
}
```

Which is the "preferred" method in terms of good coding practice?  I can fully understand why you would prefer version 2 if `kSuperDescriptiveVarName` is used more than once.  Also, does the compiler do any optimizations to make both versions effectively the same executable code?  That is, are there any performance implications here?

Case Study 2:  Use of `sizeof`

I fully understand that using sizeof versus a raw literal is preferred for portability and also readability concerns.  Take the two code examples into account.  The scenario is that you are computing the offset into a packet buffer (an array of `uint8_t`) where the first part of the packet is stored as `my_packet_header`, which let's say is a `uint32_t`.

Version 1:

```
const int offset = sizeof(my_packet_header);
```

Version 2:

```
const int offset = 4;  // good comment telling reader where 4 came from
```

Clearly, version 1 is preferred, but what about for cases where you have multiple data fields to skip over?  What if you have the following instead:

Version 1:

```
const int offset = sizeof(my_packet_header) + sizeof(data_field1) + sizeof(data_field2) + ... + sizeof(data_fieldn);
```

Version 2:

```
const int offset = 47;
```

Which is preferred in this case?  Does is still make sense to show all the steps involved with computing the offset or does the literal usage make sense here?

Thanks for the help in advance as I attempt to better my code practices.

Comment: THE reason for me is, suppose you want to use 0xBEEF in more than one place you'd have to copy-paste it which is nearly always a sign of violating DRY. If you use the constant instead, you just reuse the constant and at the moment you change BEEF to DEADBEEF everybody is happy since they get the updated value (except the beef since it;s now dead :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which is the "preferred" method in terms of good coding practice? I can fully understand why you would prefer version 2 if kSuperDescriptiveVarName is used more than once.

Sounds like you understand the main point... factoring values (and their comments) that are used in multiple places.  Further, it can sometimes help to have a group of constants in one place - so their values can be inspected, verified, modified etc. without concern for where they're used in the code.  Other times, there are many constants used in proximity and the comments needed to properly explain them would obfuscate the code in which they're used.

Countering that, having a `const` variable means all the programmers studying the code will be wondering whether it's used anywhere else, keeping it in mind as they inspect the rest of the scope in which it's declared etc. - the less unnecessary things to remember the surer the understanding of important parts of the code will be.

Like so many things in programming, it's "an art" balancing the pros and cons of each approach, and best guided by experience and knowledge of the way the code's likely to be studied, maintained, and evolved.

> Also, does the compiler do any optimizations to make both versions effectively the same executable code? That is, are there any performance implications here?

There's no performance implications in optimised code.

> I fully understand that using sizeof versus a raw literal is preferred for portability and also readability concerns.

And other reasons too.  A big factor in good programming is reducing the points of maintenance when changes are done.  If you can modify the type of a variable and know that all the places using that variable will adjust accordingly, that's great - saves time and potential errors.  Using `sizeof` helps with that.

> Which is preferred [for calculating offsets in a struct]? Does is still make sense to show all the steps involved with computing the offset or does the literal usage make sense here?

The `offsetof` macro (`#include <cstddef>`) is better for this... again reducing maintenance burden.  With the *this + that* approach you illustrate, if the compiler decides to use any padding your offset will be wrong, and further you have to fix it every time you add or remove a field.

Ignoring the offsetof issues and just considering your *this + that* example as an illustration of a more complex value to assign, again it's a balancing act.  You'd definitely want some explanation/comment/documentation re intent here (are you working out the binary size of earlier fields? calculating the offset of the next field?, deliberately missing some fields that might not be needed for the intended use or was that accidental?...).  Still, a named constant might be enough documentation, so it's likely unimportant which way you lean....

Answer (score 2):

In every example you list, I would go with the name.

In your first example, you almost certainly used that special 0xBEEF number at least twice - once to write it and once to do your comparison.  If you didn't write it, that number is still part of a contract with someone else (perhaps a file format definition).

In the last example, it is especially useful to show the computation that yielded the value.  That way, if you encounter trouble down the line, you can easily see either that the number is trustworthy, or what you missed and fix it.

There are some cases where I prefer literals over named constants though.  These are always cases where a name is no more meaningful than the number.  For example, you have a game program that plays a dice game (perhaps Yahtzee), where there are specific rules for specific die rolls.  You could define constants for One = 1, Two = 2, etc.  But why bother?

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is better to use a name instead of a value. After all, if you need to change it later, you can find it more easily. Also it is not always clear why this particular number is used, when you read the code, so having a meaningful name assigned to it, makes this immediately clear to a programmer.

Performance-wise there is no difference, because the optimizers should take care of it. And it is rather unlikely, even if there would be an extra instruction generated, that this would cause you troubles. If your code would be that tight, you probably shouldn't rely on an optimizer effect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> I can fully understand why you would prefer version 2 if kSuperDescriptiveVarName is used more than once.

I think `kSuperDescriptiveVarName` will definitely be used more than once. One for check and at least one for assignment, maybe in different part of your program.

There will be no difference in performance, since an optimization called `Constant Propagation` exists in almost all compilers. Just enable optimization for your compiler.